# Error Angular.js with Flask

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, flask

I have the following structure and code :

```
project/
       app.py
       templates/
                /index.html
       static/
             /angular.js
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>My App</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
    <div>
        {{ctrl.foo}}
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('myCtrl', [function () {
            var self = this;
            self.foo = 10;
        }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and **app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Whatever I do, I still have the following error : `UndefinedError: 'ctrl' is undefined` which I guess is due to the fact that **Flask** does not load the **angular.js**

I also tried with the static path

`<script type=text/javascript src="{{url_for('static', filename='angular.js')}}"></script>`
and
`<script type=text/javascript src="../static/angular.js"></script>`

But still no sucess... Any ideas ?

Comment: I think angular is loaded correctly: The error "UndefinedError..." looks like is angular's. Even more, if angular.js is not loaded, on the html you would see `{{ctrl.foo}}`. The html works fine on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tdhtgfd/)

Comment: I tried a `typeof angular` with `debug=False` in the console which returned `undefined`. I also tried on plnkr and with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and it works fine. So the only option left is **Flask**, I am a bit confused ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you put

```
{{ctrl.foo}}
```

in your template, Jinja looks for a context variable named `ctrl`. Your `hello_world` endpoint doesn't provide any such variable.

If you would like `ctrl` to be processed by Angular instead of by Jinja, you need to tell Jinja to include the curly braces in the rendered HTML. This can be done by [surrounding what you have in additional curly braces](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#escaping).

```
{{ '{{ctrl.foo}}' }}
```

If you don't want all of the curly braces, you have a couple of other options.

You can use Jinja's `raw` and `endraw` directives to output its contents exactly as provided.

```
{% raw %} {{ctrl.foo}} {% endraw %}
```

The other option is to [change the symbols Angular looks for](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider).

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
}]);
```

This would allow you to use

```
[[ctrl.foo]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was convinced that the error was related to the angular.js loading process.
PS : I renamed the title to "Error Angular.js with Flask"

Comment: Thanks a lot...It saved my day